# reorder GRUB to list Windows on top

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

I have **win 7** and **linux mint 14** installed. Is it possible to modify the `GRUB Menu` to show `Windows` as the first option instead of `Linux`, which it currently does. Mainly so that during boot it **starts Windows by default**.

Comment: Gosh...linux 14?? When did it get released, moreover when was linux-13 released? moreover.... :D
I guess you mean Ubuntu 14.

Comment: http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_nadia_whatsnew.php  Linux 14 => Linux mint 14

Comment: [Anthon](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/33055/anthon) Earlier in the question it was mentioned **Linux 14** , which made me wonder when did Linux kernel version 14 get released.

Comment: @beginer sorry I missed that edit.

Comment: @Anthon hah  :D  cheers man....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the order of your boot menu is important (and not just that Windows boots by default), and you don't have anything bootable besides Linux Mint and Windows (like OSX, BSD) you can do:

```
cd /etc/grub.d
mv 30_os-prober 09_os-prober
```

as the alphabetical order of the files in `/etc/grub.d`, determines in what order they are processed. Then you run `sudo update-grub`¹ to generate the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file, which determines the menu ordering.

If you just want to have Windows boot you can also change `/etc/default/grub` and change the entry

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

to

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=4
```

and run `sudo update-grub`. `4` is the normal entry for Windows after `0` for Mint, `1` for the submenu with older versions of Mint, `2` for `memcheck` and `3` for `memcheck` via a serial interface. Your setup might be slightly different, but you can count (starting from 0) while in the grub menu, or just try and change if your guestimate is off.²

There is third alternative you might want to consider, and which I myself prefer. This is to to change your `/etc/default/grub` so that it will automatically boot the system you last selected, if you don't select a different menu entry by hand. For that you change the line

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

into

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

and run `sudo update-grub`

¹ <sub>I tended to forget the name of the `update-grub` command often trying `grub-`<kbd>TAB</kbd> and hope the resulting expansions showed me the `grub-something` command I needed to run. That was until I realised that it says what to do at the top of  `/etc/default/grub` file I was editing anyway. Of course once I found out how to look the command name up, I never forgot....</sub>
² <sub>As @derobert indicated, you can also use a string that matches the menu entry you want to select. [This](https://activedoc.opensuse.org/book/opensuse-123-reference/chapter-10-the-boot-loader-grub2#grub2.etc_default_grub.options) is the only documentation I have found about that feature.</sub>

Comment: Note that GRUB_DEFAULT can be a string as well, the full title of the menu entry. This will be *much* more robust than presuming Windows is always option #4.

Comment: @derobert that is good to know. The robustness of did vastly increase some time ago (at least on Ubuntu) when the sub-menus were used to stow the 'old' kernels, but explicit is better. The non-robustness of hard-coding was one of the reasons for me to use `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT`

Comment: Thanks! i tried only the second option, and it worked!.. just one thing: i used `sudo update-grub` instead of `sudo update=grub`... i dont know if both will work.

Comment: @sunbabaphu update=grub was a typo, I corrected it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

From the answer by [Anthon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/33055/anthon), I'd replace the `mv` with `dpkg-divert` on *Debian-like* systems:

```
# dpkg-divert --add --rename --divert /etc/grub.d/09_os-prober /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
```

Then run `update-grub` as usual.

If you wish to list the available diversions, then run:

```
# dpkg-divert --list | grep os-prober
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps given in Linux Mint itself. [Linux Mint tutorials](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/341).

Comment: your link not found

Comment: @Netmoon sorry this answer is quite old and I wasnt mature enough in those days to also copy over the required pieces from the page into the answer so that even if the link expires SO has the answer. I hope you might have found the other answers helpful?

Answer (score -1):

It is pretty simple , first you have to locate the grub.cfg file, in Ubuntu it will be under /boot/grub/grub.cfg, make sure you take a back up of this file before editing.

Open the file with any text editor of your choice in sudo mode, eg sudo vi path/grug.cfg

In this file there will be menu entries , which represents each item in the boot menu. Find the menu entry corresponding to windows - note a menu entry is a set of lines.

Find a line called GRUB_DEFAULT. Now there are two ways of doing this.
1)change the value of GRUB_DEFAULT to corresponding position of windows menu item like 0 , 1 or what ever it is.
2)or cut paste the windows menu item to the corresponding position of the current value in grub_default.

CAUTION : Don't corrupt this file, if something goes wrong , replace this file with the backup.

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-30-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.13.0-30-generic-recovery-3aaa1f6c-e78d-4b56-bb71-a250d1338ea6' {
                recordfail
                load_video
                insmod gzio
                insmod part_msdos
                insmod ext2
                set root='hd0,msdos1'
                if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  3aaa1f6c-e78d-4b56-bb71-a250d1338ea6
                else
                  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3aaa1f6c-e78d-4b56-bb71-a250d1338ea6
                fi
                echo    'Loading Linux 3.13.0-30-generic ...'
                linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-30-generic root=UUID=3aaa1f6c-e78d-4b56-bb71-a250d1338ea6 ro recovery nomodeset
                echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
                initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-30-generic
        }
```