# How to reorder the grub menu--set the cursor located at the first menu automactically?

Tags: grub, reboot

There are two disks in my pc and dual os (debian--buster + win10 )installed on sda,a single os(debian buster ) installed on sdb.
Everytime to reboot pc,the grub menu show as the following:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 
Advanced option for Debian GNU/Linux
Windows Boot Manager(on /dev/sda2)
Debian GNU/Linux 10(buster) on /dev/sda6
Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux 10(buster) (on /dev/sda6)
System setup
```

If i select the first item `Debian GNU/Linux` to enter

```
df /boot/grub/grub.cfg
/dev/sdb1
```

I upload the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` as `https://www.dropbox.com/s/9qjmk178jlj2gha/grub.cfg-sdb1?dl=0`,

If i select the first item `Debian GNU/Linux 10(buster) on /dev/sda6` to enter

```
df /boot/grub/grub.cfg
/dev/sda1
```

I upload the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` as `https://www.dropbox.com/s/kf94rbc9g1xpx8e/grub.cfg-sda1?dl=0`.

My expectation:reorder the grub menu as below when to reboot pc everytime:

```
Debian GNU/Linux 10(buster) on /dev/sda6
Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux 10(buster) (on /dev/sda6)
Debian GNU/Linux 
Advanced option for Debian GNU/Linux
Windows Boot Manager(on /dev/sda2)
System setup
```

I make a adjust this way:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2  /mnt
sudo grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Reboot it ,please have a look at the grub menu.

[image]

Why the cursor located at the menu

```
Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux 10(buster) (on /dev/sdb1)
```

instead of the first menu?

How to create the below grub menu to make the cursor located in the first menu when to boot my pc everytime?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reorder GRUB to list Windows on top](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144464/reorder-grub-to-list-windows-on-top)

Comment: If UEFI, you can edit /EFI/grub/grub.cfg, if you have that file in ESP.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/957914/dual-boot-14-04-17-04-lost-grub-menu/958220#958220 Some versions do not have separate grub.cfg in ESP. Or just totally reinstall grub from prefered install. Note major upgrades to grub or Windows will reset boot order in UEFI then grub reorder/default may change. You just have to manage it when it does change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `grub-customizer` (https://packages.debian.org/buster/grub-customizer) without the need to fiddle with grub's files from Debian's official repositories, which perfectly does what you want:

[image: Move entries]

[image: Set default entry]

You can install it with the `synaptic` GUI, which comes with your standard Debian installation.

Also, don't forget to save your changes in `grub-customizer`.

Answer (score 0):

Related question : [how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Reference :

1. https://olinux.net/change-grub-boot-order-linux/
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order
3. https://wiki.debian.org/GrubConfiguration
4. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/grub2-debian-squeeze-change-boot-order-906606/

I am writing that answer which looked useful for me.

```
sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/10_linux
```

You can use `vi` or `nano` which you familiar with. Look at file in this section:

```
linux_entry ()
{
  os="$1"
  version="$2"
  recovery="$3"
  args="$4"
  if ${recovery} ; then
    title="$(gettext_quoted "%s, with Linux %s (recovery mode)")"
  else
    title="$(gettext_quoted "%s, with Linux %s")"
  fi
  printf "menuentry '${title}' ${CLASS} {\n" "${os}" "${version}"
  if ! ${recovery} ; then
      save_default_entry | sed -e "s/^/\t/"
  fi
```

While this lines looks like in my post

```
linux_entry ()
{
  os="$1"
  version="$2"
  type="$3"
  args="$4"

  if [ -z "$boot_device_id" ]; then
      boot_device_id="$(grub_get_device_id "${GRUB_DEVICE}")"
  fi
  if [ x$type != xsimple ] ; then
      case $type in
      recovery)
          title="$(gettext_printf "%s (Kernel: %s - recovery mode)" "${os}" "${version}")" ;;
      fallback)
          title="$(gettext_printf "%s (Kernel: %s - fallback initramfs)" "${os}" "${version}")" ;;
      *)
          title="$(gettext_printf "%s (Kernel: %s)" "${os}" "${version}")" ;;
      esac
      if [ x"$title" = x"$GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT" ] || [ x"Previous Linux versions>$title" = x"$GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT" ]; then
      replacement_title="$(echo "Advanced options for ${OS}" | sed 's,>,>>,g')>$(echo "$title" | sed 's,>,>>,g')"
      quoted="$(echo "$GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT" | grub_quote)"
      title_correction_code="${title_correction_code}if [ \"x\$default\" = '$quoted' ]; then default='$(echo "$replacement_title" | grub_quote)'; fi;"
      grub_warn "$(gettext_printf "Please don't use old title \`%s' for GRUB_DEFAULT, use \`%s' (for versions before 2.00) or \`%s' (for 2.00 or later)" "$GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT" "$replacement_title" "gnulinux-advanced-$boot_device_id>gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id")"
      fi
      echo "menuentry '$(echo "$title" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-$version-$type-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  else
      echo "menuentry '$(echo "$os" | grub_quote)' ${CLASS} \$menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-$boot_device_id' {" | sed "s/^/$submenu_indentation/"
  fi      
  if [ x$type != xrecovery ] && [ x$type != xfallback ] ; then
      save_default_entry | grub_add_tab
  fi
```

I am very beginner at Shell. That's why I am not making any changes.

If you want to change the title of kernels from partitions other than the main partition, then you want to edit the

`/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` file

in this section:

```
linux)
      LINUXPROBED="`linux-boot-prober ${DEVICE} 2> /dev/null | tr ' ' '^' | paste -s -d ' '`"
      prepare_boot_cache=

      for LINUX in ${LINUXPROBED} ; do
        LROOT="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 1`"
        LBOOT="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 2`"
        LLABEL="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 3 | tr '^' ' '`"
        LKERNEL="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 4`"
        LINITRD="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 5`"
        LPARAMS="`echo ${LINUX} | cut -d ':' -f 6- | tr '^' ' '`"

        if [ -z "${LLABEL}" ] ; then
          LLABEL="${LONGNAME}"
        fi

    if [ "${LROOT}" != "${LBOOT}" ]; then
      LKERNEL="${LKERNEL#/boot}"
      LINITRD="${LINITRD#/boot}"
    fi

        cat << EOF
menuentry "${LLABEL} (on ${DEVICE})" --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
EOF
```

Here's the [answer link](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/grub2-debian-squeeze-change-boot-order-906606/#post4491204).

Comment: I would say to professional Linux user to create new answer and you can add information from this answer if you want. I am not against the rule.

Comment: While the answer is okayish for headless machines, it is way too overly complicated. You've even admitted it, you won't even make any changes since you're not familiar with shell. You should then use a GUI as much as you can for anything you want to do, this will prevent you much headaches for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for live boots anyways. (I only work in live mode).

I'm not sure if you still care about this, but I am sure somebody will benefit. If you go to the config folder under your grub folder, there is a bootmenu.cfg file. In the file, the last paragraph or so is what you seek.

Notice that this snippet begins with "set_default_entry". How keen. Here, we want to change the first if statement default "language_keyboard_timezone".

```
set_default_entry

if is_enabled l10n_menu; then   
   if [ -z "$lopts" ]; then
      set default="language_keyboard_timezone"
      set timeout=-1
   else
      set default="linux"
      set timeout=60
   fi
fi
```

If you are wanting to change it to your linux OS bootup, then you must find out what the name is for that menu. This can be found in the grub.cfg file in the grub folder. See "set default".

```
set default=linux

menuentry " MX-21.3 x64 (January 15, 2023)" "$kernel" "$initrd" "$kopts" --id=linux {

kernel="$2"
initrd="$3"

shift 3

linux /antiX/${kernel} quiet splasht nosplash $@
initrd /antiX/${initrd}.gz
}
```

In this example, it is "linux". And as validation, we can see my distro name just below it, MX-21.3 x64. This default entry, "linux", also happens to be the same as set in the else statement in the first code snippet.